# java sockets - keep track of how many socket files an application already has created

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, socketexception

I am programming a simple application in java using sockets. I recently ran into an error:

> java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

I have a couple of Questions regarding sockets now:

- I started to wonder how I could avoid exceptions like this? ergo how can I keep track of how many socket-files my application already has created? And what is the limit?
- And also, am I right with the assumption, that the `socket.close()` method deletes the respective socket-file?
- Where are the socket-files located? And does this question depend on what operating system I work with? Because in Linux i know sockets are handled with files (like pretty much everything else), but i have no idea about windows etc.

Comment: I don't know the exact name of the file created, neither in Linux, nor in Windows. But - 1. those are restricted by system, that it is system/user account dependent. Admin can change the number of those files, you can get that using `ulimit -n`; there is yet another global level number. 2. Yes,as the connections are closed, the files are removed in that order. See this for more ---> http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-fix-javanetsocketexception-too-many-open-files-java-tomcat-weblogic.html & this one ---> https://doc.nuxeo.com/display/KB/java.net.SocketException+Too+many+open+files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how I could avoid exceptions like this?

- Ensuring that `socket.close()` always gets called. Call `socket.close()` from finally block.
- Increasing the maximum open files limit.
- `socket.close()` does not mean the socket is immediately reusable after closing. It will be reusable after twice the [MSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_lifetime), since it goes to **TIMED_WAIT** state after closing. So if a lot of sockets are in **TIMED_WAIT** state you should consider using a [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).

> how many socket-files my application already has created?

You can find this by `netstat -nalp|grep {pid}|wc`.

> what is the limit?

You can find the limit on maximum number of files that a process can open using `ulimit -n` in linux. An open socket is considered as an open file. This limit can be increasing by moidifying `/etc/security/limits.conf` file.

> does socket.close() method delete the respective socket-file?

Yes in linux a socket file is deleted when `close()` method is called for that socket.

> where are the socket-files located?

In linux the open file descriptors are under `/proc/{pid}/fd/`. I'm not sure about windows.

Comment: One more left to answer ---> Is it true that the socket.close() method deletes the respective socket-file? Please answer completely, I'd upvote this answer. Answer with as well as without reference of the connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

Sockets use File Handles, and the error you get just means you have too many handles open. That can be any OS resource which uses the File Handles. It doesn't mean there's a file somewhere on your drive (actually there are not for Sockets).

On Windows, you can see how many handles are open in the Task Manager, process view. Just add the column.

In Java, the responsability to close a resource is given to the object/process opening the resource. So, if you don't open it, do not close it. If you open it, close it, always.

A best practice since Java 7 is to never use object.close(), but use the `Closable` interface along with

```
try( Socket mySocket = new Socket() ) {
    // code here
}
```

This guarantees that your resource will be closed and is safer and more readable than

```
Socket mySocket = null;
try {
    mySocket = new Socket();
} finally {
   if ( mySocket != null ) mySocket.close();
}
```

Comment: You didn't answer any of OP's questions! you just mentioned why try-with-resources of Java 7 should be adopted! If possible, please improve your answer.